# PHP For each displaying all the results 10 at a time

Tags: php, youtube

Currently I am working with [YouTube's API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) for returning the related videos of a video, it returns the 15 results with the following.

```
get https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&relatedToVideoId='.$id.'&type=video&maxResults=16&key='.$key.'
```

But how can I return this data in a `foreach` instead of just printing it, with the following.

```
print '<pre>';
    print_r($related);
print '</pre>';
```

I'm not a developer but I'm trying to learn.. I would like for it to display 10 results, and then an option to show more which will show another 10.

The results I'm getting from the above code goes as following.
http://pastebin.com/5ikPeFQm

Comment: Can you share the data you are receiving in result?

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($related);` ?

Comment: @mith updated post, I removed a lot of the results as it's pretty much just the same information going on until it reaches `50`

Comment: @Wayward this result contains no. of things, which one you want to display using foreach?

Comment: @SahilGulati the title only of each post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreach() loop to get items:

```
foreach($related['items'] as $item){

 echo 'videoId --->'.$item['id']['videoId'];
 echo '<br>';
 echo 'publishedAt--->'.$item['snippet']['publishedAt'];
 echo '<br>';
 echo 'title--->'.$item['snippet']['title'];
 echo '<br>';
 echo 'description--->'.$item['snippet']['description'];

}


if(isset($related['nextPageToken'])){
    echo '<a href="url?nextPageToken='.$related['nextPageToken'].'">load more</a>';
}
```

Comment: This will display my results up until 15, thanks! However can you link me somewhere where I can learn about adding a show more button that will display the next 15 results when pressed?

Comment: see my edits.., hope it will help you. also set maxResults=15 to get 15 results @Wayward

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is required result.

```
foreach($related["items"] as $data)
{
    echo "Title: ".$data["snippet"]["title"]."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your links arrays or Dictionary look like :

```
$Urls = array ("http 1" ,"http 2" ,"http 3","http 4" ,"http 5",
              "http 6" ,"http 7" ,"http 8" ,"http 9" ,"http 10",
              "http 11", "http 12","http 13","http 14","http 15",
              "http 16" ,"http 17" ,"http 18" ,"http 19" ,"http 20",
              "http 21" ,"http 22" , ".....etc");
```

then you call your links source array like that :

```
  $Outeveryten = array_chunk($Urls , 10);

  foreach  ($Outeveryten as $result ) {

    foreach ($result as $values ) 
    print $values . " <br> ";  
    echo "<br> __________________ <br>"; 
    }
```

now the result will be like you ask ( **display every 10 results** ) :

---

http 1 
http 2 
http 3 
http 4 
http 5 
http 6 
http 7 
http 8 
http 9 
http 10

---

http 11 
http 12 
http 13 
http 14 
http 15 
http 16 
http 17 
http 18 
http 19 
http 20

---

http 21 
http 22 
.....etc

---